# How can I amplify volume with Audacity and ffmpeg?

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, audacity

I have an MP4 recording where the video is present, but much too quiet. What I've done before is:

```
ffmpeg -i master.mp4 -i amplified.wav -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

I've tried various permutations, and the output `ffmpeg` builds is, as viewed by my browser, at the original overly quiet volume. If I load the Audacity-generated .wav, it plays as loudly as intended. (N.B. I have enabled clipping in Audacity, and I have not noticed it to fail at the amplifications I've tried with it.) However, the final result seems to retain unaltered the original audio track along in the video.

How, with present software or other software, can I assign `amplified.wav` to be the new audio track to `master.mp4` in `output.mp4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic stream selection was recently tweaked in June, and it inadvertently broke in some cases, especially for audio. Workaround is to explicitly map audio.

```
ffmpeg -i master.mp4 -i amplified.wav -map 0:v -map 1:a -vcodec copy output.mp4
```